# GFX-drivers for HP Probook 4300s

Tags: 12.10, graphics, hp

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my HP Probook 4330s laptop and everything seems to run fine,  besides the graphic card drivers. When I go into `settings -> details -> graphics` it says `Driver: Unknown`.

I checked [HP driver site](http://www.hp.com/), and it only had GFX-drivers for SuSE distros.

How can I get the proper drivers for this machine?

---

No, I haven't. Does it only find out what kind of card I have, or does it actually download the proper driver for me? Thank you though, I'm dowloading it now.

Comment: Have you tried installing "mesa-utils" package?
If you are using the integrated card it should be recognized.